# using $group and $match (with range of date) functions in pymongo query

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

i m trying to execute the following sql query in Mongodb

```
select organization from users
group by organization 
having 2014-07-10 > date > 2014-07-10
```

(i dnt knw if SQL syntax is correct or not, but i hope i have given a rough i what i m trying to do here)

first i tried to see how many users were added yesterday

```
>>> users.find({u"timeCreated":{"$gte":date_yesterday, "$lt":date_today}}).count()
6
```

now i tried to group the users by the organizations to which they belong and used the following monogo aggregate query

```
>>> user.aggregate([{'$group':{'_id': "$organization",'count':{"$sum":1}}},{"match":{u'timeCreated':{"$gte":date_yesterday, "$lt":date_today}}}])
```

result was

```
{u'ok': 1.0, u'result':[]}
```

that is no such query.

i even tried using the following query to get all entries dated before today

```
>>> user.aggregate([{'$group':{'_id': "$organization",'count':{"$sum":1}}},{"match":{u'timeCreated':{"$lt":date_today}}}])
```

but the output remains the same.

the following command works fine and give a list of organizations

```
>>> user.aggregate({'$group':{'_id': "$organization",'count':{"$sum":1}}})
```

can any one tell me where i m going wrng??

P.S. I m new to mongoDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other way around. You want to match the items first

```
user.aggregate([
   {"$match": {'timeCreated':{ "$gte":date_yesterday, "$lt":date_today } }},
   {'$group':{'_id': "$organization",'count':{"$sum": 1 } }}
])
```

Also note that as this is a "pipeline" operations like **`$group`** or **`$project`** are "destructive" and only emit the fields you actually specify.